# How to asynchronously iterate an ObservableCollection containing hierarchical elements?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, observablecollection

I write C# WPF application using MSVS 2015. I'm interested in asynchronouse processing of hierarchical ObservableCollection. I have an ObservableCollection instance containing hierarchical elements:

```
public class Group : ProfileElementType
{
    . . . . . .
    const ushort deviceAddress = 1;
    . . . . . .
    private ObservableCollection<ProfileElementType> _childProfileElenents;
    [Browsable(false)]
    public ObservableCollection<ProfileElementType> ChildProfileElenents
    {
        get { return this._childProfileElenents; }
        set { this_childProfileElenents = value; }
    }
    public Group()
    {
        . . . . .
        this.ChildProfileElenents = new ObservableCollection<ProfileElementType>();
        . . . . .
    }
    . . . . .
}
```

ProfileElementType class is the base one for Group class and Register class. You can see the detail definition of ProfileElementType, Group and Register classes in my post on [Why is InvalideOperationException thrown when I try to serialize to XML an ObservableCollection containing hierarchical elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058259/why-is-invalideoperationexception-thrown-when-i-try-to-serialize-to-xml-an-obser) My collection can comprise both Register instances and Group instances. Each Group instance can involve other Group instances and Register instances in its ChildProfileElenents
ObservableCollection. I have a root Group instance that has all other groups and registers in its ChildProfileElenents collection (root collection). I've written a recursive function that synchronously processes the root collection. Here it is:

```
private void pollDeviceRegisters(ObservableCollection<ProfileElementType> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
       return;
    foreach (ProfileElementType elem in collection)
    {
        if (elem.ElementTypeName == "Group")
        {
            Group group = elem as Group;
            pollDeviceRegisters(group.ChildProfileElenents);
        }
        else
        {
            Register reg = elem as Register;
            // Get this register' value from outer device via serial port using MODBUS RTU protocol.
            ushort[] aRes = ReadHoldingRegisters(deviceAddress, reg.Number, 1);
            reg.CurrentValue = aRes[0].ToString("X");
        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of registers in outer device - not less then 2000. So this synchronouse sequential function works slowly by the reason of types conversion in each iteration and serial port read timeouts. So my application hangs while the function works. I'll be very grateful if you show me how to write abovementioned operation asynchronously. For example how to write pollDeviceRegisters recursive function using **Parallel.ForEach** method from TPL or **async/await** approach. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BlockingCollection for the reading of the serial port and move that part to a new thread if that is the bottle neck.

```
private Task pollDeviceRegisters(ICollection<ProfileElementType> collection)
{
    var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Register>();

    // This starts three threads to start reading the serial ports (arbitrary number of threads to start you will need to see what is optimal)
    var pollingTask = Task.WhenAll(ReadSerialPort(blockingCollection),
        ReadSerialPort(blockingCollection),
        ReadSerialPort(blockingCollection))
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            blockingCollection.Dispose();
            return task;
        });

    BuildDeviceRegisters(collection, blockingCollection);

    return pollingTask;
}

// Creates a new thread and waits on the blocking collection
private Task ReadSerialPort(BlockingCollection<Register> collection)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var reg in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // Get this register' value from outer device via serial port using MODBUS RTU protocol.
            var aRes = ReadHoldingRegisters(deviceAddress, reg.Number, 1);
            reg.CurrentValue = aRes[0].ToString("X");
        }
    });
}

// flattens the hierarchical data
private static void BuildDeviceRegisters(ICollection<ProfileElementType> collection,
    BlockingCollection<Register> blockingCollection)
{
    if (collection != null)
    {
        //using a stack instead of recursion (could switch to ConcurrentStack and use Parallel.ForEach() but wouldn't mess with it if not bottle neck)
        var stack = new Stack<ICollection<ProfileElementType>>(new[] {collection});
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var element = stack.Pop();
            foreach (var item in element)
            {
                var group = item as Group;
                if (group != null)
                {
                    // push the tree branch on to the stack
                    stack.Push(group.ChildProfileElenents);
                }
                else
                {
                    blockingCollection.Add((Register)item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Mark we are done adding to the collection
    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
}
```

I didn't test this code.

Also this returns a Task that will need to be awaited to know when the reading of the serial ports are done. Once you start using the TPL you will see a lot of methods will need to be changed to be async and awaited.  You can also put a limit on the adding into a blocking collection if you are adding too much into the collection and hogging a lot of memory which will make the add method block until the consumers take from the collection.

Comment: Guys, ofcourse I bag your pardon but the example of using async-await in my case would be magnificent. Can anybody present it?

Comment: Unless how you read the serial port software has task methods (what ever the code is in ReadHoldingRegisters) then this is probably te best you'll get with async await.  When you call pollDeviceRegisters you should use the await modifier and make that method as async which then trickles up everywhere in your code.

Comment: How can I use CancellationToken in my case? Can I define CancellationToken instance in outer code, change from "foreach (var reg in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable()){}" to "while(collection.TryTake(out reg, 50, cancellationToken){} and set cancellationToken.Cancel() in outer code?

Comment: CharlesNRice, your code runs fastly but ObjectDisposedException has place two times today.

Comment: Are you awaiting the call into pollDeviceRegisters?  You could comment out the dispose of the blockingcollection but I doubt that's it.  What's more likely is you have a resource that is needed and depending on the race condition it's being disposed of before the task is complete. Which is why it would be important to await the call.